# Spark does not recognise Cent symbol

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, dataset, symbols

I'm using Spark version 2.3.1, and Scala version 2.11.11 to read a parquet file with `spark.read.parquet("..."`

However somehow the cent sign in the file, namely`¢`, got converted to a `?` when I print out the dataframe using `df.show()`.

It was kept as `?` thourgout the application run and written out as `?` How do I preseve the cent symbol `¢` or anyone could help explain why this occured? Many thanks. I want to write out the result as `¢` in text file.

Comment: The `¢` character is ASCII 162 (hex A2). That is beyond the original set of ASCII printable characters, which ends with `~` (ASCII 126, hex 7E).  Many rendering engines will use `?` to indicate a character that isn't printable (by that particular engine). It seems likely that something similar is happening here.

Comment: Thanks. But when it writes out , it also writes `?`. So it's not only a render thing?

Comment: If by writes out you mean that reading the output text file shows `?`?  That would indicate that the program reading the text file can't render `¢`.  Can you use a hex editor to read the file?  If it shows `A2` where the `¢` should be, then all is actually well.

Comment: No that's not the problem. yes I used a text editor to read it as well. The text editor definitly can render cent sign as it did for other files.